# How can I use ng-repeat to render this JSON data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to repeat the below JSON without write for loop using only ng-repeat

```
$scope.cart = {
    "product": [
        {
        "HH_STYLENUM": "2204-RYP",
        "SIZE_QTY": [
            { "QTY": "11", "SIZE": "XS" },
            { "QTY": "11", "SIZE": "XL" },
            { "QTY": "111", "SIZE": "S" },
            { "QTY": "111", "SIZE": "M" },
            { "QTY": "111", "SIZE": "L" }
        ],
        "HH_CUSTID": "2919",
        "HH_ADDCART_UNITPRICE": "11.5",
        "HH_ADDCART_NO": "188",
        "HH_ADDCART_DATE": "2014-12-10 00:25:07.0",
        "HH_ADDCART_STATUS": "CART",
        "HH_COLORID": "15991"
        },
        {
        "HH_STYLENUM": "2204-HHSH",
        "SIZE_QTY": [
            { "QTY": "01", "SIZE": "XS" },
            { "QTY": "03", "SIZE": "XL" },
            { "QTY": "104", "SIZE": "S" },
            { "QTY": "51", "SIZE": "M" },
            { "QTY": "31", "SIZE": "L" }
        ],
        "HH_CUSTID": "2919",
        "HH_ADDCART_UNITPRICE": "11.5",
        "HH_ADDCART_NO": "188",
        "HH_ADDCART_DATE": "2014-12-10 00:25:07.0",
        "HH_ADDCART_STATUS": "CART",
        "HH_COLORID": "15991"
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Is there something specific you want to ng-repeat over?

Comment: what do you wanna get form this json ?

Comment: I want repeat the without any specification of i value for EX if want SIZE_QTY key value xx =  $scope.cart.product.SIZE_QTY in ng-repeat s in xx {{s}} without mention any key position like this xx = $scope.cart.product[0].SIZE_QTY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments... you could use two ng-repeats. One to loop over cart.product and within that ng-repeat, another ng-repeat to loop over SIZE_QTY

```
<div ng-repeat="product in cart.product">
      <p ng-repeat="size in product.SIZE_QTY">{{size.SIZE}}</p>
```